# Struct packing in GCC on 32-bit doesn't work?

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, g++, pragma

I have inherited some third-party code in a project. It's comprised of a header file and a binary library without sources, so I cannot just recompile it with different settings.

The header uses a compile-time assert-like trick (`typedef`ing a negative-size array if expression fails) to ensure proper struct alignment, but it doesn't seem to work in 32-bit mode.

Here's a stand-alone little program that captures the entire problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#pragma pack(push, 8)
struct test {char _; long long a;};
typedef char pack_test[(offsetof(test, a) == 8) ? 1 : -1];
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("%d\n", offsetof(test, a));
        return 0;
}
```

The code above fails to compile both on clang 3.0 and on any recent gcc version I could quickly lay my hands on (4.5 to 4.7): the packing pragmas simply have no effect whatsoever. The compiler keeps aligning the member `a` to 4 bytes (you can check that by commenting the `typedef` out).

Why is that? How can I fix the code so that this assertion doesn't fail and keep it compatible with the ABI while not having to go over all the structs in the header and tacking `attribute`s onto their tails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a 32-bit system, a `long long` may not need an alignment of eight bytes, four should be enough. After all, you still fetch two entire words from memory, whether the first of them is eight-byte aligned or four.

You can try to force eight byte alignment with an attribute

```
struct test { char _; long long a __attribute__ ((aligned(8))); };
```

(probably wrong, I'm not familiar with gcc's attributes)

Of course, you can also add a dummy member to the `struct` to ensure the desired alignment

```
struct test { char _; char dummy[7]; long long a; }
```

That should work in practice.

Comment: Yes, that was precisely it! I added the `__attribute__ ((aligned (8))` and it works now. Thank you!